# Regex match between tags if they contain a target

Tags: java, regex, string, string-matching

I have a String which has tags `BEGIN` and `END` which enclose any numbers or letters `A-Z 0-9` with no spaces.

I want to match the tags with a certain target.

For example, given the `String` `BEGIN11119991112AADFSFENDBEGINASSD12UHYEND` and the target `999` this would match

`BEGIN11119991112AAdFSfEND` and **not** `BEGINASSD12UHYEND`

Ive tried `BEGIN.*999.*END`

I assume it needs a lookahead to check the target comes before the end tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
BEGIN(?:(?!BEGIN).)*999(?:(?!BEGIN).)*END
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qQ0fV9/1)

Comment: can you help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50199958/finding-enclosing-tag-conatining-specific-text?noredirect=1 ?

Comment: @emilly I am traveling for 2 days and accessing this site on mobile. Will be able to edit after I reach back.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
BEGIN(.*999.*?)END
```

After matching, you would be able to get that number alone.

If you don't want matching then:

```
BEGIN.*999.*?END
```

You were almost correct, just need to add `?`.

**[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/dC6iN0/1)**

Comment: No, this regex won't work if a `BEGIN...END` block (without `999`) comes before `BEGIN.*?999.*?END` for example: `BEGINfooENDabcd123BEGIN11119991112aAdfsfENDBEGINASSd12UHYEND`

Answer (score 1):

### Best of both worlds

```
BEGIN((?:(?!BEGIN).)*999.*?)END
```

Match `BEGIN` followed by, and capturing, the following group: zero or more of this non-capturing group: any character that doesn't match `BEGIN`; followed by `999` followed by zero or more of any character until the first match of, but not including, `END`.